# Access forbidden error while creating sendGrid API Key

Tags: api, sendgrid

When I am creating General API key on SendGrid its saying access Frobidden, I am not getting what to do,  I opened ticket for that, Hope any one knows about this issue.
Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to log out and log back in and then try creating an API key again? Perhaps your session expired.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that this happens because your account is still being provisioned?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Multiple User Credentials account was being used. **You have to use main account in order to create API keys**.